# How to get Sitecore Pipelines to run along with /API calls

Tags: pipelines

Our team is running Sitecore 8.2 Update 4 using a traditional MVC configuration.

We wrote a pipeline that will inject CORS HTTP headers into the response that are configured via an item in Sitecore. However, it would appear that when we actually make the API call, we don't get any headers back. Here's an example of what we are doing:

When we make `https://www.mywebsite.com/api/Stations/GetStates`, we get these headers:

> Cache-Control →no-cache
>
> Content-Length →658
>
> Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Date →Mon, 11 Jun 2018 17:35:59 GMT
>
> Expires →-1
>
> Pragma →no-cache
>
> Vary →Accept-Encoding
>
> X-ADC →08/09
>
> X-Frame-Options →SAMEORIGIN
>
> X-ID →PZW33CS
>
> X-Powered-By →ASP.NET

As you can see, the `Access-Control` headers are missing, and those are inserted using a Sitecore pipeline.

We've found out that there is some sort of handler that are defined in the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` that says this:

```
<handler trigger="~/api/" handler="sitecore_api.ashx"/>
```

If we change the call to `https://www.mywebsite.com/api2/Stations/GetStates` (changing the route from **api** to **api2**), then we get the headers that we are expecting:

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Content-Type
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods →POST, OPTIONS
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin →https://www.myOtherSite.com
>
> Cache-Control →no-cache
>
> Content-Length →637
>
> Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> Date →Mon, 11 Jun 2018 17:43:26 GMT
>
> Expires →-1
>
> Pragma →no-cache

So, it looks like the API handler is messing with things. After doing some research, we can't find that file anywhere in the webroot, so we're not sure how to override/change this behavior. So our questions are:

1. Is that API route something that should be reserved for Sitecore only calls?
2. What is the best way to have Sitecore not bypass the pipelines for our API call? Is it truly to use some sort of unique api naming structure such as `https://www.mywebsite.com/myapi/Stations/GetStates`?

Comment: What `pipeline` was your processor that updated the `CORS` headers being invoked by, `<httpRequestBegin>` or `<mvc.requestBegin>`?

Comment: We created a new pipeline in the `mvc.requestbegin` section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Is that API route something that should be reserved for Sitecore only calls?

   - Yes, `/api/` is a reserved space by default. One of the services that falls under this area is the [Item Service](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_itemservice). And if I recall correctly, hijacking this area (declaring a route in your `global.asax` or `initialize` or setting a site definition virtual path to it) results in bad behavior on the shell side of things because some Speak pages use the services in this space.
2. What is the best way to have Sitecore not bypass the pipelines for our API call? Is it truly to use some sort of unique api naming structure such as https://www.mywebsite.com/myapi/Stations/GetStates?

   - Usually when I am trying to make a backend MVC style call to a controller (JSON, partial HTML, whatever), I end up using `/api/Sitecore/ControllerName/ActionName` as my route with really no additional setup needed (that I recall).

Comment: That is a very handy trick. It would appear that when you shortcut by using the `/api/ControllerName/ActionName` you don't get the Sitecore pipelines, but when you add the `Sitecore` name after the api, then everything gets called as you expect. That's nice to know. Thanks for the clarification!